# Incorrect Method Name in Python Logging Output: Always Displays 'logging:callHandlers:1706' Instead of Actual Method Name

Tags: python, logging

I am encountering an issue with Python logging.

The expected method name in the log output is replaced with `logging:callHandlers:1706`

Initially, my log entries displayed in the format `[level] [date] [method] [text]` but now the 'method' field consistently shows 'logging:callHandlers:1706.'

I have ensured that each file contains the line `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` and that I sistematically use this logger variable for logging (eg: `logger.error(f"Deleting job task for: {e}"`))

Comment: Well, what happened between "Initially" and "now"?

Comment: Can you post a full code snippet?